# Can pygame use vector art?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

http://cache.kotaku.com/assets/resources/2008/02/dbzburstcell.jpg

-edit- bassically just detailed vectorized 2d games.

When making a side scroller in pygame or any other comparable 2d framework with python, can you utilize graphics such as in the above link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can always render your vectors to bitmaps with enough resolution and use the rendered version in the game, instead of rendering everything in runtime -- that seems to be what the game you linked above does.

That said, you could use [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) to render `.svg`s at runtime. There's even a [tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame) available.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just needed to know if it is possible for my design process.